# Thingsboard client subscription

Tags: mqtt, thingsboard

I have to publish data via MQTT on thingsboard.io using Arduino and simultaneously fetch the data on the same board.
Is it possible to do so? if yes then how?

Otherwise, I would need a sample code for client subscription to a topic on thingsboard.io

Answer (score 1):

yes, you can do so.

Thingsboard, use the same topic but it differentiates on the basis of Token no assign to your device.

For publishing the payload to thingsboard:-

```
// Prepare a JSON payload string
  String payload = "{";
  payload += "\"temperature\":"; payload += temperature; payload += ",";
  payload += "\"humidity\":"; payload += humidity;
  payload += "}";

  // Send payload
  char attributes[100];
  payload.toCharArray( attributes, 100 );
  client.publish( "v1/devices/me/telemetry", attributes );
  Serial.println( attributes );
```

For Subscribing:-

```
 client.susbcribe("v1/devices/me/telemetry")
```

As your device will both connect to MQTT broker and authorised via Token no, so Token is only responsible for one to one connectivity with MQTT Broker